# VSCode Python Debugger steps on lines not being executed--and over lines being executed

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I'm working on a Python project, and I've been using the VS Code Python debugger frequently, using breakpoints or just using the step over/into tool to understand how my code executes.

After making some changes to a single Python file, the debugger started behaving strangely. **While the script itself is executing as expected** (based on logs and expected side effects), when I step through the script with the debugger **it skips over lines that clearly are being executed, and stops on lines that clearly are not being executed.**

For example, after setting an early breakpoint and using only "Step Over" to navigate through the execution of my script, the debugger highlighted the following lines, individually in sequence:

1. An if statement (normal [expected to resolve as true based on variable values])
2. Each line of the if block (normal)
3. The first line of the corresponding else block (not normal)--without stopping on the else statement itself (also not normal)
4. The second line of a try block, without stopping on the try statement itself, or on the first line of the try block (not normal)--and without stopping on any of the other lines in the above else block

... (many more lines)

5. The second line of an if block, for which the if statement resolved to false, without stopping on the if statement itself or on the first line of the if statement (not normal)
6. The second line of a finally block, without stopping at the else statement or else block corresponding to the above statement(not normal)--or on the finally line itself, or on the first line of the finally block (not normal)

Again, I can clearly tell this is not how the code is executing. Referring to steps 5 and 6 above: the code generates an email as coded in the else case, and does not generate an email as coded in the if case.

If I revert the file to its previous state, the debugger behaves normally. Using git diff, I can tell there are no differences in blocking, parentheses, whitespace, etc. between the previous version and this one.

Am I missing something? I don't believe I ever had this issue before.

1. I don't understand how changing the code would change the behavior of the debugger
2. This issue renders the debugger essentially useless for my intention of understanding the behavior of my code.

Comment: Did you reload Python process after your code has changed? Looks like the debugger have another version of runtime code.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're asking. However, I've saved the code, restarted VS Code, and reinstalled the Python extension for VS Code.

Comment: And that's helped?

Comment: My apologies that I wasn't clear. I took all those steps before posting this question--they did not change anything.

Comment: My VScode Python debugger has also started to act crazy today. Refuses to execute some code. Refuses to F11 correctly sometimes. Opens up a copy of the debugged file, title is in italics sometimes. Breaks on a comment sometimes. etc etc. I have latest V 1.43.2.

Comment: Also, my code seems to run correctly when not in debug. (5 mins. leeway to change a comment is WAY TOO SHORT. C'mon SO you been told this numerous times. Please extend to at least 10 or possibly 15 mins.)

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to explain, let's suppose you've the code:

```
1 if True:
2     if False:
3         a = 1
4 else:
5     b = 2
6 try:
7     c = 3
```

Then you run Python with debugger, it stops on 1st line.
Next you remove 2nd line in IDE and got actual code:

```
1 if True:
2     a = 1
3 else:
4     b = 2
5 try:
6     c = 3
```

Many frameworks uses watchdogs in development mode to autoreload project when source files changed (also some debuggers could do that on-the-fly for specific changed module). But if your edit doesn't trigger reloading of Python you've got situation where script executes lines in order:

- 1 (if True)
- 2 (if False)
- 4 (else)
- 6 (try)

and IDE will stops on these lines but with wrong statements:

- 1 (if True)
- 2 (a = 1)
- 4 (b = 2)
- 6 (c = 3)

Comment: Thank you, that makes perfect sense. I've observed that behavior before, when I had edited code without saving the file. This time, I just did not imagine it could be the same fundamental issue giving me trouble--after not only saving my file but also restarting my IDE.

For me, what logically follows is this: is there some way one can **ensure** that Python / the project is reloaded?

Comment: Check this https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/49209#issuecomment-386742954

Comment: @frost-nzcr4 Unless I have missed something the OP did not change any code between starting the debug process and the issues occuring. Your answer does not seem to apply and may/will confuse. If I did miss the relevant part in the OPs post that you are explaining then I stand corrected.

Comment: I've just found that VSCode's ptvsd uses under the hood PyDev.Debugger aka pydevd 1.3.3 that's so old, recent version is 1.9.0. In previous versions there are bugs in module hot reloading that might led to this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing the exact same problem (lines appearing to be skipped during debug, etc.), probably caused by ptvsd not working with the actual up-to-date source file. I've managed to work around this by adding the following to my workspace settings, which disables an experiment:

```
"python.experiments.optOutFrom": [
    "PtvsdWheels37 - experiment"
],
```

Without the above workaround, the problem occurs sporadically for me -- I haven't been able to pin down exactly when it occurs. I've created the issue https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/11716 on this.